# Extract my own "local items" keychain from Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, keychain

How can I extract the passwords keychains from my "local items" keychains on my own computer - All from Terminal?
I do not want any pop ups.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keychain Services Secure Notes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22370552/keychain-services-secure-notes)

Comment: Not really because that does not show how to avoid the pop up too... As I was searching for. :-)