# Are Secure Notes in macOS KeychainEncrypted?

Tags: macos, security, encryption, keychain

As I review the idea of using macOS Keychain, I see the ability to store Secure Notes.
I also came across the following entry here:
[Keychain Services Secure Notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22370552/keychain-services-secure-notes)

This seems to suggest that though "Secure Notes" access is constrained by a password, using command line instructions, you can actually reveal the CONTENT of Secure Notes in plain text. Does this mean that Secure Notes are NOT encrypted and the content can be extracted as long as you can identify the title of the note (at least that is how I am reading the above thread).

Also, it seems that the way Secure Notes works is that once entered, the only way to retrieve one is to know some part of the title, otherwise, there is no way to just list all the Secure NOtes. Is this how it is supposed to work? Is there a way to list all saved Secure Notes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All keychain items are stored encrypted on disk. They are decrypted into the memory after providing the necessary credentials and user consents.

There are ways to list all keychain items like secure notes programmatically via the Keychain API, but as soon as an application tries to access any keychain item, MacOS comes up and asks the user to grant the required privileges and his/her password.

So setting the possible code vulnerability flaws aside, secure notes are secured!

To extract the plain text content of a secure note via command line, use this snippet: (Let the name of the secure note is `Test`)

`security find-generic-password -C note -s "Test" -w | xxd -r -p`

It may ask for your password twice.

Comment: Thx for the quick reply. what do you make of the example in the link that shows the content of a secure note in plain text via command line instructions?...(see section marked "Now we are getting somewhere! The result of decoding it is:

<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NOTE</key>
    <string>12345
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
HELLO WORLD
=)
</string>
    <key>RTFD</key>

Comment: thx again but I see that command. What I am asking is whether that command means that since it reveals the secure note this suggest that the content are not truly secure, or that the content are easily retrievable? Or are you saying the only way the command works is by asking for the password for the secure note?

Comment: Actually the command that I've posted is a bit different than the one in the original post. My command will reveal the **plain text** of the note. And yes, the only way that it works is by asking the password from the user. (Can't use the pass from the command line)

Comment: sorry did not catch that...I see now yours has the extra part at the end "| xxd -r -p". what does that do differently?

Comment: It converts the `hex` output of the `security` command to the plain text.